# The last character of a string doesn't display when i debug with mingw-w64

Tags: c++

I'm using MinGW-w64 when I debug with visual studio code, the last character of a string isn't been displayed. I've tried with codelite but the result is the same.
How can I fix it?
Thanks.

** ERROR:**

[image: Error]

Comment: show code and error in text form, not in images

Comment: The same code runs and produces the expected results on my machine (gcc version 8.1). Maybe update your compiler? Nothing really comes to mind since this is rather unexpected behaviour for such simple code.

Comment: Here's your code compiled with three different compilers, checking three different standards: https://godbolt.org/z/rhZF4M - It's all good. `** ERROR **` isn't a diagnostic message any of the compilers I know spit out. Give us the full message please.

Comment: Have you tried to print the variable that contains the string? Something like `cout << a << endl`?

Comment: The same program with printing: https://godbolt.org/z/X3LpO5

Comment: Seems like debugger-debug time for me.